# redirect to https on ovh and azure using single rule

Tags: php, azure, .htaccess

I'm creating a simple website that I want to host on OVH and Azure, to test if it will work in both environments.
I'm struggling with .htaccess.
When I add below code it correctly redirects move from HTTP to HTTPS on OVH:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this doesn't work on Azure. There I must use below code (found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/06/19/http-to-https-redirect-for-azure-web-app-on-linux/)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-ARR-SSL} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

but this doesn't work on OVH.
I'd like to unify those rule into one, so it will work in both environments.
The reason for unification is that I'm using a CI server that is deploying the same code to both environments.

I've tried these RewriteCond's:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-ARR-SSL} ^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
```

but had no luck. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you will have two separate host names, so you can easily add to an if else statement if you have Apache 2.4.

For example

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'foo'">
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</If>
<Else>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-ARR-SSL} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</Else>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I'm getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Azure.